# Atom git-plus error: no such identity

Tags: git, atom-editor

I use Atom and the `git-plus` package and ssh on Windows 10.

When I try to `pull` or `push` I got the following error: `no such identity: /.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory`. If I `push` or `pull` with the Git-Bash all works fine.

Some idea where the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow the instructions from phphoenix: https://github.com/akonwi/git-plus/issues/224

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).